# Why a char variable overlaps the char array after it in the input console when it 's casted to ((char*)&)? in c++ codeblocks

Tags: c++

When i cast a char var. using this operator "&"( i really have to cast it to write it in a char [] to write it in a file as a fixed length record ) the casted value is the char concatenated to the char [] which i wrote in the input console after it . (if the next attribute was not char [] no thing happens and it does not overlaps only if it is a char [] it overlaps) . Because of that prob. i can not maintain that records are written correctly . Anyone know why this prob. happens? Thanks in advance .

I have tried to search and found that casting char to ((char*)&) is not safe . but i still can not understand how casting process used the char [] attribute after it in the console of input

The code that refers to the problem:

```
struct citizen
{

    char gender ;

    char name [10] ;

};

istream& operator>>(istream& in, citizen& c)

{  
     in >>c.gender ; // input f 

     in>>c.name ; // iput mariam 

     cout<<c.gender ; // outputs "f"

     cout<<(char*)&c.gender; // outputs " fmariam"

     return in ;

}
```

Comment: C style strings stop when they happen to find a null terminator (zero byte)

Comment: `&c.gender` is already a `char*`; the cast isn't doing anything.

Comment: A single character is not a "string".  A C-style string is an ARRAY of zero or more characters, terminated by a 0 character.

Comment: no @chris i cast char to (char*)& or & ..yes i mentioned both of them but i have explained that i want to cast (char)  not (&char)

Comment: Q: What happens if you simply do `cout<<c.gender`?  You get an `f`, don't you?  And `cout << c.name` gives you `mariam`. So why the casting nonsense?

Comment: i cast to use it i another part in the code as i have mentioned " (i really have to cast it to write it in a char [] to write it in a file as a fixed length record )" @paulsm4 .. i will not use the object it self but i will operate on it

Comment: What are you _trying_ to do? It seems like you want `cout<<c.name;` instead of outputting `gender` more than once.

Comment: @MariamAhmad, I'm a bit confused then because the code is casting `&c.gender` to `char*`, not casting a `char` to `char*&`.

Comment: @MariamAhmad: You might be in for a few surprises here - C++ doesn't work as you think. For instance, there is a very good chance that your compiler makes `sizeof(citizen)==12`, or even 16 - not 11. This may not match your fixed structure on disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stream insertion operator requires that a `char*` inserted into the stream points to an array of characters terminated by the null-character.

`char gender` is not a null-teminated array of characters (unless the value happens to be the null-terminator, in which case it can be treated as an array of one characters representing an empty string as far as pointer arithmetic is concerned).

By inserting the non-null-terminated `char*` into the stream, you violate the requirement mentioned above, and as a  result, the behaviour of your program is undefined.

> why this prob. happens?

Because the behaviour of your program is undefined.

Comment: well .. Thank you .. i quite understood ,but i want to understand better from you if you are not busy i will try to summary this problem in a better way. this was a question in File organization and processing course . and i have to write records in a file using fixed length structure . so i have to write the attributes of the record in a char array or a buffer then write the whole char array in the file in a fixed length .. and to put attributes in the char [] i have to use strcpy and strcat which require casting the attributes to be (char*)& .. i will continue in another comment

Comment: @MariamAhmad You cannot use `strcpy` or `strcat` with non-null terminated characters either. Either use a null-terminated array to store `gender` or use `strncpy` or `memcpy` to copy it. Or simply use assignment.

Comment: the problem is that when i casted the char it changed and was concatenated to the char[] after it . somehow i understood from you and another answer why that happened . and i have debugged and found the it is concatenated to what i have entered in the input console after it .but if i changed the char [] to string and wrote it after  the char this problem will not exists . so the problem happened specifically because i used char [] after char because when i used a string after it no problem happened.so why the string did not overlap the char attribute but the char [] did? Thank you in advance

Comment: @MariamAhmad I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: i will explain what i mean in points .. 1) i cin the object by overloading it's attributes for example (char gender  = f and  name = mariam (will not determine it's data type now))..2) i will have to cast attributes to write it in a char array to write it in a file

Comment: 3) as i debugged when i cast a char variable to ((char*)&) there will be two scenarios .. if the name is char [] .. i will find in the buffer the gender is written "fmariam" not f  and if i cout <<(char*)& gender ; i will find it" fmariam" .. the another scenario if the name was string .. i will find in the buffer only f and if i cout <<(char*)& gender ; i will find only f also .. so what makes a difference from a char[] to a string (or another data type as they do not make problem also)

Answer (score 2):

The `<<` operator for `cout` depends on the type of its argument. `c.gender` is a type `char`, so `cout` outputs its character value. `&c.gender` is the address of a char... analogous to a `char *` (so your cast doesn't do anything). As a `char *`, `cout<<` interprets the reference as an array of characters, terminated with a `'\0'` character, aka a "nul terminated string." Since the fields of the `struct` are packed, `cout` doesn't see a `'\0'` until the end of the array of characters adjacent to the gender field.

You're kinda lucky your program didn't crash.